# How to set response header in Mule 4

Tags: mule4

I am developing one REST API from Mule 4, and trying to set a response header, but I am not getting the perfect answer.

Could you please help me to get the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the responses in the `<http:headers>` element of the response.

Example:

```
<http:listener path="test" allowedMethods="GET" config-ref="httpConfig">
   <http:response statusCode="200" reasonPhrase="Response OK">
       <http:headers>
           #[{
              "key1" : "value1", 
              "key2" : vars.someValue}]
       </http:headers>
   </http:response>
</http:listener>
```